# Python: Why "return" won´t print out all list elements in a simple for loop and "print" will do it?

Tags: python, list, return

Im trying to print out all elements in a list, in Python, after I´ve appended one list to another. The problem is that it only prints out every element when I use PRINT instead or RETURN. 
If I use print it prints out the whole list in a column with "None" at the end of the list, but return will print out just the first item. Why?

This is the code:

```
def union(a,b):
    a.append(b)
    for item in a:
        return item


a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[4,5,6]
print union(a,b)
```

It returns:

> 1

If I use

```
def union(a,b):
    a.append(b)
    for item in a:
        print item

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[4,5,6]
print union(a,b)
```

instead, I get:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> [4, 5, 6]
>
> None

(and not even in a single line).

Please note that I´ve found more results with this issue ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465412/why-isnt-this-code-returning-these-lists-does-this-have-to-do-with-using-retu)), but they are not quite the same, and they are quite complicated for me, I´m just beggining to learn to program, thanks!

Comment: This is because `return`... returns. You end your loop at the first item and nothing else is done...

Comment: The pythonic way to merge `iterables` object is with `itertools.chain()` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use a `return` statement, the function *ends*. You are returning just the first value, the loop does not continue nor can you return elements one after another this way.

`print` just writes that value to your terminal and does not end the function. The loop continues.

Build a list, then return *that*:

```
def union(a,b):
    a.append(b)
    result = []
    for item in a:
        result.append(a)
    return result
```

or just return a concatenation:

```
def union(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` means end of a function. It will only return the first element of the list.

For your `print` version, `a.append(b)` makes `a = [1,2,3,4,[1,2,3]]` so you will see the elements before `None`. And the function returns nothing, so `print union(a, b)` will print a None.

I think you may want:

```
def union(a, b):
    a.extend(b)
    return a
```

Or

```
def union(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def union(a,b):
    a.extend(b)
    for item in a:
        print item,
    return a


a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[4,5,6]
union(a,b)
```

prints

```
1 2 3 4 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement will, as the name suggests, make the function return, thus stopping any iteration of the surrounding `for` loop (in your code, the `for` loop will iterate only once).

If you want to return the result of the two "concatenated" lists, as a single list, this will work:

```
def union(a,b):
    a.append(b)
    return a
```

If you expected the `return` to behave differently, probably you are confusing it with the `yield` keyword to make generator functions?

```
def union(a,b):
    a.append(b)
    for item in a:
        yield item

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[4,5,6]
for i in union(a, b):
    print i
```

This code will also print every element in the list resulting from appending `b` to `a`.

Basically, what the `yeld` does, is suspend the current execution of the method, which will resume the next time starting from after the `yield` itself (until the `StopIteration` will be risen because the `items` in `a` will be finished).